# Does a psion need a ranged basic?

Tags: dnd-4e, psionics

I'm putting together my first psion. The race will be human, and the focus will be telekinesis. While choosing powers, I've keyed on the special feature of the "Kinetic Trawl" power: "You can use this power unaugmented as a ranged basic attack."

Since human psions get a free, unaugmentable, at-will power, I'm keen to take Kinetic Trawl as that power. But I'm wondering if I shouldn't take something like Static Mote instead. Do I really need a ranged basic when basically *every* psion power is ranged and at-will?

Comment: Uh, yeah, pretty much _all_ character generation is opinion based. But this question is outlining the specific build decisions and asking if a specific ability really even fits with it (according to others's experience). That's not really opinion based. But whatever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not really.

There are really only a few times that you're going to need a Ranged Basic Attack (RBA). That would be when you're granted an attack from a leader character. There are certain feats and other abilities that affect ranged basic attacks, but this power would not qualify for those as it doesn't read "Can be used as a Ranged Basic Attack" and is instead used itself when you would make one.

So if you have a Shaman, Warlord or Bard who will be granting attacks in your party, this *might* be a good choice. But look at your other party members. Most likely you've got a striker or two and a defender. Those guys are going to be getting those granted attacks way more often than you will. It's probably not worth it to invest in that as your bonus at-will.

Something else to consider: as of Essentials, the human can take the encounter power Heroic Effort instead of the bonus at-will. This can be a nice little "failed my save...No I didn't" power or can make a missed attack a hit. It's worth looking at closely before you grab that unaugmentable third at-will.